# CakePHP strange behavior

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

We're using CakePHP to develop some in-house apps, but since yesterday my colleague has a strange behavior with his setup.

We use Netbeans as IDE on a Windows XP SP3 with Apache http server by ApacheLounge and PHP 5.2, but all the modifications he do on the ctp's are not showing when the app it's rendered on the browser.

I'm the most expoerienced user of CakePHP here, and it's the first time since I'm using CakePHP that I have that issue.

What I do:

- Clear all cache, temp files
- Update CakePHP to 2.4.2
- Created a new htdoc directory

If anyone had suffered the same behavior please gime some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the reason of the bad behavior: my colleague create an scaffold of the controller, so CakePHP was on the fly creating all the views.